# radio button default checked value based on variable output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck to make this work. I have an array `@names = ['abc', 'bbc', 'xyz']` for which I am building the radio button as follows.

```
<% @names.each do |n| %>
<%= f.radio_button :name, n, :checked => "checked" %>
  <%= f.label :name, n.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

I have another variable `@select = 'bbc'` which contains the string which has to be selected among the above radio buttons. Currently the last radio button is getting check i.e, `'xyz'`. How to achieve this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually setting the attribute `checked="checked"` to every radio input, which does not make sense since Radio Buttons are there for **a single answer among multiple choices**.

Add a small test to check only one radio button:

```
<% @names.each do |n| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :name, n, :checked => n == @select %>
  <%= f.label :confidentiality_level, n.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

Long version:

```
<% @names.each do |n| %>
  <% if @select == n # tests if n is equal to 'xyz' or whatever %>
    <%= f.radio_button :name, n, :checked => "checked" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.radio_button :name, n %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :confidentiality_level, n.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works smooth

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I'd just add this as a comment but I don't even have enough reputation to do that at the moment!

Just a small refactor the checked option accepts a boolean so there's no need for the ternary operator: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button

```
<% @names.each do |n| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :name, n, :checked => n == @select %>
  <%= f.label :confidentiality_level, n.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

Really just personal preference but all things equal (e.g. readability), less code is better.