# Default checked value for check_box based on array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432469/radio-button-default-checked-value-based-on-variable-output). I am feeling stupid about asking this but I am not able to solve it.

```
@default_svn_repository = ["svn_software", "svn_hardware"]
```

`@svn_repos = ["svn_software", "svn_hardware", "svn_documents", "svn_test1_sw", "svn_test2_hw", "svn_test3_documents"`]

```
<% @svn_repos.each do |repos| %>
 <%= check_box("feature", "svn_repos", {:multiple => true, :checked =>  @default_svn_repository.each {|dsvn| repos == dsvn ? true : false}}, "#{repos}", nil) %>
  <%= h repos -%><br />
<% end %>
```

@default_svn_repository is a variable which has an array of what needs to be checked by default. In my example above among all the check boxes, svn_software & svn_hardware needs to be checked. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `check_box_tag` rather than `check_box`. Here is what should work.

```
<% @svn_repos.each do |repo| %>
 <%= check_box_tag(repo, repo, @default_svn_repository.include?(repo)) %>
  <%= h repo -%><br />
<% end %>
```

Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
@default_svn_repository.each {|dsvn| repos == dsvn ? true : false}
```

does not return true or false. It returns the whole array of @default_svn_repository hence all values appear checked. For ex :

```
 [1,2,3].each{|x| x == 3 ? true : false}
```

when run on console will give you [1,2,3]. That is what is happening with your code. True or false should be generated properly.

Instead just check if the current repos value is present in the @default_svn_repository array and you should be fine.